# pytorch concat layers with sequential

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

So I used nn.Sequential several times before but now I'm experiencing a weird error where one layer will send 3 outputs to the next one instead of two (like expected)

I have defined my layer as :

```py
class BidirectionalGRU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, rnn_dim, hidden_size, dropout=0.0, batch_first=False):
        super(BidirectionalGRU, self).__init__()

        self.BiGRU = nn.GRU(
            input_size=rnn_dim,
            hidden_size=hidden_size,
            num_layers=1,
            batch_first=batch_first,
            bidirectional=True,
        )

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        x, hidden = self.BiGRU(x)
        return x, hidden
```

And I use it in my code here:

```py
class Listener(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self, input_feature_dim_listener, hidden_size_listener, num_layers_listener
    ):
        super(Listener, self).__init__()
        assert num_layers_listener >= 1, "Listener should have at least 1 layer"
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size_listener
        self.gru_1 = nn.Sequential(
            BidirectionalGRU(
                rnn_dim=input_feature_dim_listener,
                hidden_size=hidden_size_listener,
                batch_first=True,
            ),
            BidirectionalGRU(
                rnn_dim=hidden_size_listener * 2,
                hidden_size=hidden_size_listener,
                batch_first=True,
            ),
            BidirectionalGRU(
                rnn_dim=hidden_size_listener * 2,
                hidden_size=hidden_size_listener,
                batch_first=True,
            ),
            BidirectionalGRU(
                rnn_dim=hidden_size_listener * 2,
                hidden_size=hidden_size_listener,
                batch_first=True,
            ),
        )

    def initHidden(self):
        return torch.zeros([2, 8, 512])

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.squeeze().permute(0, 2, 1)
        fake_hidden = self.initHidden()
        output, hidden = self.gru_1(x, fake_hidden)
        #output, hidden = self.gru_2(output, hidden)
        #output, hidden = self.gru_3(output, hidden)
        #output, hidden = self.gru_4(output, hidden)
        return output, hidden
```

This DOESNT WORK and throws me an error:

```
    las(spectrograms, spectrograms, 0.5)
  File "/Users/jaime/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "caca.py", line 116, in forward
    listener_feature, hidden = self.listener(batch_data)
  File "/Users/jaime/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "caca.py", line 84, in forward
    output, hidden = self.gru_1(x, fake_hidden)
  File "/Users/jaime/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

But If i define every layer manually instead of using `nn.Sequential` and pass the output,hidden myself then it works:

```py
class Listener(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self, input_feature_dim_listener, hidden_size_listener, num_layers_listener
    ):
        super(Listener, self).__init__()
        assert num_layers_listener >= 1, "Listener should have at least 1 layer"
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size_listener
        self.gru_1 = BidirectionalGRU(
            rnn_dim=input_feature_dim_listener,
            hidden_size=hidden_size_listener,
            batch_first=True,
        )
        self.gru_2 = BidirectionalGRU(
            rnn_dim=hidden_size_listener * 2,
            hidden_size=hidden_size_listener,
            batch_first=True,
        )
        self.gru_3 = BidirectionalGRU(
            rnn_dim=hidden_size_listener * 2,
            hidden_size=hidden_size_listener,
            batch_first=True,
        )
        self.gru_4 = BidirectionalGRU(
            rnn_dim=hidden_size_listener * 2,
            hidden_size=hidden_size_listener,
            batch_first=True,
        )
    def initHidden(self):
        return torch.zeros([2, 8, 512])

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.squeeze().permute(0, 2, 1)
        fake_hidden = self.initHidden()
        output, hidden = self.gru_1(x, fake_hidden)
        output, hidden = self.gru_2(output, hidden)
        output, hidden = self.gru_3(output, hidden)
        output, hidden = self.gru_4(output, hidden)
        return output, hidden
```

This works perfectly. I would like to make my code create multiple layers based on an argument and using `nn.Sequential` with a for loop inside would allow it.